# JSON formatting: using sharepoint list item into email body

Tags: json-formatting, if-condition, variable

I'm trying to include a list item in combination with plain text inside my email body. The body includes multiple if conditions to generate language dependent text. But I keep getting code back for my variable list item. If I remove the plain text it works. So I guess my code is not entirely good.

What I did:

```
"&body=",
        "=if([$UserLocation]=='A','The device is from [$Brand]',if([$UserLocation]=='B','L'appareil provient de [$Brand]')
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you add full JSON code to your question? Also, I see there is single quote (`'`) in your text (L'appareil provient de [$Brand]) which might be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Sorry for the question that isn't a question anymore :)

```
"&body=",
    "=if([$UserLocation]=='A','The device is from '+[$Brand],if([$UserLocation]=='B','L'appareil provient de '+[$Brand])
```